# Stored Procedure not returning all values when using Like

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I'm building a .NET Application using SQL Server.

Currently, I am trying to get a stored procedure to return all rows with Titles similar to the given string, ignoring accents and allowing users to pass incomplete versions of the title.

E.g.

Poke, Poké, Pokémon, Pokemon, and Pokemon X, should all *ideally* return the row "Pokémon X".
However, currently, none of the given parameters are returning anything. (Swagger UI just shows '[]' in the response body).

When I pass Pokémon X, the return Title is correct, but none of the other data is accurate (Id is 0, all other columns are null).

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Pokémon X",
    "platform": null
  }
]
```

**Game Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Game] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]    NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Platform] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGame_GetSimilarTitles]
    @LikeTitle VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Game]
    WHERE [dbo].[Game].[Title] LIKE '%' + @LikeTitle + '%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI;
END
```

**Function to retrieve data**

```
 public Task<IEnumerable<Game>> GetSimilarTitles(string likeTitle) =>
            _db.LoadData<Game, dynamic>("dbo.spGame_GetSimilarTitles", new { LikeTitle = likeTitle });
```

**API** (Note: this is a simplified version)

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<Game>> Test(string title)
        {
            var similarGames = await _games.GetSimilarTitles(title);

            return similarGames;
        }
```

**LoadData function**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> LoadData<T, U>(
            string storedProcedure,
            U parameters,
            string connectionId = "Default")
        {
            using IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_config.GetConnectionString(connectionId));

            return await connection.QueryAsync<T>(storedProcedure, parameters,
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
```

Comment: What's the DDL for the `dbo.Game` table - including `COLLATION`s?

Comment: I'm new to SQL, what do you mean by the DDL? I've added the Table Schema also as I forgot to include it

Comment: [The SP seems to work fine for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/4iS_7bGV). It may be worth debugging and stepping through to see exactly what is being passed to the database here, or setting up an SQL Trace to do the same. One thing to note is that your parameter type (`VARCHAR(100)`) doesn't match the data type of the column you are searching (`NVARCHAR(100)`) but this doesn't make a difference with the sample data you have provided.

Comment: I've run a manual SQL Query in Visual Studio, and the results return exactly what your JSFiddle and @patrick-hurst 's answer show, so I assume the issue lies with the GetSimilarTitles function?

Comment: I've also added the LoadData function, as this is not a built in function. This is written dynamically so I can use it across multiple calls, rather than just specifically the GetSimilarTitles usage. It works fine with other stored procedures that return IEnumerables with no parameters, or Single Game objects with parameters, but not IEnumerables with Parameters. Based on your comment and Patrick's answer I'm assuming the issue lies in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you're not switching between data types and collations for BOTH sides of the predicate (the column and your variable).

Consider:

```
DECLARE @Game TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, Title NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL, Platform NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
INSERT INTO @Game (Title, Platform) VALUES ('Pokémon X', ''),('Pokemon Ruby', '')

DECLARE @LikeTitle NVARCHAR(100)

SET @LikeTitle = 'Poke'
SELECT *, @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI AS SearchedString
  FROM @Game
 WHERE Title COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI LIKE '%' + @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI + '%'
 
SET @LikeTitle = 'Poké'
SELECT *, @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI AS SearchedString
  FROM @Game
 WHERE Title COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI LIKE '%' + @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI + '%'

SET @LikeTitle = 'Pokémon'
SELECT *, @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI AS SearchedString
  FROM @Game
 WHERE Title COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI LIKE '%' + @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI + '%'
 
SET @LikeTitle = 'Pokemon'
SELECT *, @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI AS SearchedString
  FROM @Game
 WHERE Title COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI LIKE '%' + @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI + '%'

SET @LikeTitle = 'Pokemon X'
SELECT *,  @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI AS SearchedString
  FROM @Game
 WHERE Title COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI LIKE '%' + @LikeTitle COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp850_CI_AI + '%'
```

```
Id  Title       Platform    SearchedString
--------------------------------------
1   Pokémon X               Poke
2   Pokemon Ruby            Poke

1   Pokémon X               Poké
2   Pokemon Ruby            Poké

1   Pokémon X               Pokémon
2   Pokemon Ruby            Pokémon

1   Pokémon X               Pokemon
2   Pokemon Ruby            Pokemon

1   Pokémon X               Pokemon X
```

Comment: This, plus republishing my database, resolved this issue. Thank you and @GarethD for the help!